# I want to create swagger file with karate framework.Is there any way to Create swagger file with karate?

Tags: karate

I want to create swagger file with karate framework.Is there any way to Create swagger file with karate? Or Share swagger file creation process.

Could anyone please provide a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible currently. It may be something added to the IntelliJ plugin in the future: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19232-karate